# Buffering log4net Debug-Messages to display them on error?

Tags: c#, error-handling, log4net

Most of us start using logging with the output of DEBUG messages. When the project runs for a while usually we reduce the output to INFO or even WARN levels.

But when an error occurs I just miss that DEBUG-Messages before the error came up. So this is what I want:

Just log from INFO or above. But when an error occurs I also want the DEBUG-messages that appeared before. Is there an appender or code snippet to achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Log4net has an appender for just this purpose: ´BufferingForwardingAppender´.

This tutorial contains everything you need:
http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-8-Lossy-Logging.aspx

Comment: Link seems to be dead. But "BufferingForwardingAppender" should help me anyway. Thanks

Comment: I can only assume that this is a temporary problem. It was still working when I posted it...

Comment: The tutorial is now available again.